# Retrieve last week saturday date in hive

Tags: hive

Is it possible to retrieve last saturday date in Hive.

Need the output in this format i.e "2014-11-01".

Whenever the query is run it must return last saturday date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this

```
select  CASE 
WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'EEEE')="Friday" 
THEN Date_add(CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24,'yyyy-MM-dd') as String),-5)
WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'EEEE')="Thursday" 
THEN Date_add(CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24,'yyyy-MM-dd') as String),-4)
WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'EEEE')="Wednesday" 
THEN Date_add(CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24,'yyyy-MM-dd') as String),-3)
WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'EEEE')="Tuesday" 
THEN Date_add(CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24,'yyyy-MM-dd') as String),-2)
WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'EEEE')="Monday" 
THEN Date_add(CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24,'yyyy-MM-dd') as String),-1)
WHEN from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(),'EEEE')="Sunday" 
THEN Date_add(CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24,'yyyy-MM-dd') as String),0)
ELSE Date_add(CAST(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-1*60*60*24,'yyyy-MM-dd') as String),-6)
END
from fun;
```

output

```
2014-11-01
```

Comment: It is throwing a error  "-ksh: syntax error: `WHEN' unexpected
" for the second line. What is fun here??

Comment: Worked on ksh and bash shell.fun is simply a table (any table) which have minimum one record on it. I have to tell you that time. if it will work,Make it correct.

Comment: is there any record in table??

Comment: create table fun(xyz String);
load data local 'test' overwrite into table fun;

in fun table there is a record 2014-11-05

then run the above command

Answer (score 2):

Below query will work to solve your problem:

```
SELECT  date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'u') AS int) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Danila Ganchar is right. Thats the smartest and fastest way of finding the Saturday of last week.

SELECT  date_sub(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()), cast(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'u') AS int) + 1);